# jQuery: Dynamically add class that belongs to another element

Tags: jquery, class, dynamic, addclass

I want to add a class to an element that belongs to the element that was just clicked. The class changes but they all begin with fa-.

So I want to dynamically get the class of the element that was just clicked, and add it to a different element. I tried this but for some odd reason it doesnt work.

```
$(".fa").on("click", function() {

    var Icon = $(".icon");

    Icon.addClass($(this).attr("class").match(/fa-[\w-]*\b/));

});
```

I even alerted this to make sure its getting the class and it is.

```
alert($(this).attr("class").match(/fa-[\w-]*\b/))
```

Comment: can you add html and a fiddle?

Comment: Heres an example http://jsfiddle.net/opb48aLc/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`match()` returns a `String` object, not a primitive `string`; it needs to in order to add those extra properties to it. jQuery doesn't seem to like `String` objects; perhaps it tests via `typeof ... == 'string'`, which returns false for a `String` object.

Simply adding `+''` to force it to a `string` makes it work:

```
 selectedOptionIcon.addClass( $(this).attr("class").match(/fa-[\w-]*\b/)+'' );
```

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/opb48aLc/3/).

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".get-from-this").on("click", function() {

  var selectedOptionIcon = $("#add-to-this");
  selectedOptionIcon.addClass($(this).attr("class").match(/fa-[\w-]*\b/).toString());
});
```

Comment: Both this and the first solution work, although which is better?

Comment: prefer use the +'' than .toString()

Comment: @UserDy I suppose i'm biased here, but the general mark of the better answer is one that explains the code.